# PowerShell-script with invoke-command gets stuck on specific computers

Tags: powershell, active-directory, invoke-command, foreach-object

I'm writing a PowerShell-Script that reads all shares from all AD-Servers and outputs them into a csv-file. At the same time the script is saving all occuring errors and outputs them into an error-log. The script will be run as a weekly task.
When I run the script, all goes well until it gets to one specific server on which it just loads infinitely. The AD-Server (Windows Server_2012_R2) is inside a normal OU and other servers in this OU work fine.

I believe that there are a few others on which the problem occures as well but I'm not sure how many exactly (about one in 150).

It does not produce an error.

Do you know what could be the Problem here?

Code:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'

$computers = (Get-Content C:\PowerShell\Shares\serverlist.txt).ForEach({
    if(-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_))
    {
        "$_.domain.com"
    }
})

$remoteCode = {
    Get-SmbShare | Where-Object Path | Get-Acl |
    Select-Object -Property "PSChildName", "Path", "Group", "AccessToString"
}

$results = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock $remoteCode 2>&1
$errors, $good = $results.Where({$_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]}, 'Split')

$good | Sort-Object PSComputerName | Select-Object "PSComputerName", "PSChildName", "Path", "Group", @{ Name = "AccessToString"; Expression = { $_.AccessToString -replace("268435456", "FullControl") -replace("-1610612736", "ReadAndExecute")}} | export-csv -path C:\PowerShell\Shares\shares.csv -NoTypeInformation -delimiter ";"

$errors.Exception.Message | Set-Content $error_logfile -Encoding Unicode
```

Comment: Sounds like a server specific issue. Besides slight modification you can make to your script, it looks fine to me. Can you remote into that server and try the commands manually? Even a `Enter-PSSession` might help.

Comment: I tried Enter-PSSession and the same happened. I can't find anything on the web that fixes it though... Do you have any idea?

Comment: Different PowerShell version?

Comment: We have version 5.1.17763.2268. I don't think I am able to install a different one because we are very limited at our tools when it comes to installing (company rules)...

Comment: I'm still learning about running parallel jobs in PowerShell, so I thought I would check to see how Invoke-Command works.  Based on the documentation, and especially example 8, I don't think your code is running parallel jobs.  Running the jobs in parallel will not fix the one problem, but it does allow you to get all the data from all the other servers even if one gets stuck.  I've been doing this by sending computer names to the Split-Pipeline module, it works great!  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I now found the problem. Two servers where frozen and that resulted in the never ending PowerShell script. Now I think I will configure some Sort of timeout, does anyone of you know how I could do that the best way?
Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Please don't use the "Answer" box to ask additional questions. Instead [ask a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, will do.